# Fast way to calculate cosine similarity for a very large, very sparse matrix?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As some background information on my problem: I have a large number of sets of integers, about 15 million. Each set ranges in size from 1 - 25 elements. I have one set for each unique integer value.

For a smaller examples let's say I have five unique integers: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`
My sets might look something like:

```
[1, 3, 4]
[2, 5]
[3, 1, 4]
[4, 1, 3]
[5, 2]
```

As you can see the sets tend to have overlap as the elements within a set are related to each other. If the set for `1` contains `3`, and `4`, the sets for `3` and `4` are likely to have a lot of overlap (but not guaranteed to be exactly the same.)

My goal is to find which of these sets are most similar.

To that end I have formed a sparse vector for each set, and use a 1 or a 0 to indicate whether the integer from the sorted, unique set of all integers exists in that set.

So for the above example, the sparse matrix would look like:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

I think want to calculate the cosine similarity of this matrix by using the `columnSimilarities` function on `RowMatrix`, to find which unique integers have sets that are most similar, essentially clustering them.

The problem is that my real dataset has about 15 million distinct integers, so each sparse vector has 15 million entries.

The vast majority of the entires are 0, as there's at most 25 elements in each set.

The `columnSimilarities` function takes a very long time to run. I've never actually seen it finish.

Is there some way to optimize my data, perhaps leveraging the fact that it is incredibly sparse?

Comment: Why not to use `SparseMatrix` (or even your own matrix) and define your own `columnSimilarities` for this? It's not hard: for vectors x, y columnSimilarities(x, y) = dot(x, y) / (norm2(x) * norm2(y)), and norm2 definition is very simple, as well as dot definition. And you can store (indices of) pairs of N most similar vectors in TreeMap (or some other collection), and periodically remove values with small similarity from this map.

Comment: maybe it's even simpler to define or to use SparseVector.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin I'm definitely not opposed to the idea, but why would this be more efficient than using the built in `columnSimilarities` on `RowMatrix`?

Comment: Another issue I think I would run into is let's say I put all my sparse vectors in an `RDD[Vector]`. Since you can't access an RDD within a `map` or `foreach` on another RDD, I'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: because of `RowMatrix#columnSimilarities` has `O(n)*O(m^2)` complexity, where n is number of elements in a row (for dot operation, including zeros), and `m^2` is a number of possible rows combinations. While using sparse matrix complexity is about `O(25)*O(m^2)`, witch is much less. Also my variant requires much less RAM usage for matrix and for result store (and much less disk usage), with benefit in speed.